# Using a submit button to submit to the same form and using the values to run SQL queries

Tags: javascript, html, sql, forms

sorry the title is slightly confusing but it was the best way I could think to describe it. So my issue is that I am creating a form for people to put certain data into it. Part of the validation for the form is to compare current values to past values from the database. To do this I need to process the form to get certain identification fields in order to find the user's last entry into the database. The way it is supposed to work (in my head) is: User fills out data, hits the check button (a type=submit button) then the form runs its validations based on previous DB entries and enables the submit button for the user to click to perform final submission. Any idea or suggestions? Right now my check button submits the form but can't do all the proper validations because I need some of the form data to pull some SQL Queries.

Comment: You'll want to add some code my friend!

Comment: Personally what I would do is validate each form input with AJAX calls to a PHP file then if everything's ok, Enable the final submit button.

Comment: I didn't add code just because I wanted more of the conceptual how to go about this moreso than debugging code or what not. I like to figure out the actual writing of the code myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making the check button a type=button. That way you can set the onClick event handler to call a function to do your validation via ajax without submitting the form to the server.

Comment: Thanks! Yea I wasn't using ajax and some hours of google searching along with your answer helped me realize what to do a bit. Thanks again!